# Hyper-V encountered an error while configuring the network

Tags: hyper-v

I've ran into a "little" problem while I was trying to create a virtual machine (Windows Server 2012 R2). The reason why I am trying to create the virtual machine is educational (we need to do it thanks to the University I am studying at).

The problem I am facing is saying that Hyper-V encountered an error while configuring the network.

Please note that I already did check the services and the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" is already set to run when Windows starts and it's set to automatic (and obviously is already running at the moment of talking). I am unsure on what to even try at this point because I can't find a possible solution to deal with this.

Has anyone had this exact sort of problem where the issue continued even after making sure the VM Management service is running? Also, I did check in my BIOS, and the VM option is enabled.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

After trying about 4 suggested fixes, I managed to get Hyper-V to work again by following these steps:

1. Disable/remove the Hyper V feature:

   `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V`
2. Reboot
3. Re-install the Hyper V feature:

   `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

Source: https://knarfalingus.net/2018/07/01/hyperv/hyper-v-encountered-an-error-trying-to-access-object-on-computer

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of the VM settings, and a screenshot of virtual switches in Hyper-V virtual switch manager . Also, if you could provide more detail about the error message .

Please check if all Hyper-v features are installed :[image]

Comment: Hello! Actually, I am unable to even open the Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager as it provides me with an error (i.imgur.com/6rx1u4o.jpg) which I have tried to find a workaround for, but was unsuccessful. As for the Hyper-V VM creation error, this is the screenshot of it: i.imgur.com/guSpgM6.jpg

Comment: Sorry , but i can't view the images . Can you try to upload in original post using image button .

Comment: I have updated the original post. As for the Hyper-V Extensible Switch, it gets disabled after I click on OK.

Comment: if all features are there , please try to create a virtual switch using powershell :  New-VMSwitch -Name "External VM Switch" -AllowManagementOS $True -NetAdapterName Ethernet                          here is a usefull link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/connect-to-network

Comment: I had tried that way, but I believe since I am using Wi-Fi (and am unable to use Ethernet in any way), it won't let me create a vSwitch (as I get a generic failure error).